# Testing existence of documents in Solr

Tags: solr, solr4

First off, please excuse our Solr ignorance.

We have a web application that has both public and private projects. The public data is the only data that should be getting added to Solr. We have a set of tests that run through behaviors of the site that create both public and private data, and, for added certainty, we'd like to test whether those private documents were indexed by Solr.

One way to do this is by doing a wildcard query and then searching those results for the private data (specifically, unique project titles). But, because this is a query, it seems like there is a chance that the project may not have met a certain threshold in index weights to appear in the query, but could, eventually, should the weights increase. We have considered exporting the indices using Luke, but the export is an extremely time consuming task. We also don't know what the indices will look like when documents are deleted so as to make this solution viable.

We don't want a private project to slip by and then, one day, have it show up in search.

Is there a solution for this? Will a wildcard query return EVERY document indexed by Solr? There are also probably questions we don't know we should ask.

Thanks for your time (and patience)!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have multiple projects with the same name, I don't know why searching for a project by name would fail to find what you are looking for.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding your concern.

To return all indexed documents, the query `*:*` can be used.